# C# - Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, sqlexception

I am trying to make a login page connected to sql server but whenever I enter username and password the next line of code

```
var user = db.Admins.Where(a => a.username.Equals(usertext)).SingleOrDefault();
```

throws the next exception:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Unable to create a constant value of
> type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'. Only primitive types or
> enumeration types are supported in this context.'

How should I resolve it?

Here is the code of the login:

```
AirlineEntities db = new AirlineEntities();
if (usertext.Text != string.Empty && passtext.Text != string.Empty) 
{
    var user = db.Admins.Where(a => a.username.Equals(usertext)).SingleOrDefault();
    if (user != null)
    {
        user.password.Equals(passtext);
        MessageBox.Show("Login successful");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect password");
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Enter Username and Password please");
}
```

Comment: `var user = db.Admins.Where(a => a.username.Equals(usertext.Text)).SingleOrDefault();`

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to compare a username with a `TextBox`. You want to compare it with a string, so you almost certainly want to use the `Text` property again. Additionally, you're currently calling `Equals` for the password, but ignoring the result. I suspect you want something like:

```cs
if (usertext.Text != string.Empty && passtext.Text != string.Empty) 
{
    var user = db.Admins.Where(a => a.username.Equals(usertext.Text)).SingleOrDefault();
    if (user != null && user.password.Equals(passtext.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login successful");
    }
    else
    {
        // Note: message updated because we don't know whether the user
        // wasn't found, or they didn't have the right password
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect user name or password");
    }
}
```

Or perhaps simpler:

```cs
string user = usertext.Text;
string password = passtest.Text;

if (user != "" && password != "")
{
    var userEntity = db.Admins.SingleOrDefault(a => a.username == user);
    if (userEntity is object && userEntity.password == password)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login successful");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect user name or password");
    }
}
```

Also note that it looks like you're storing passwords in plain text, which is *very* weak security. I would strongly recommend that you use an out-of-the-box identity system instead of rolling your own like this.